# pointer from integer w/o cast warning when calling lfind

Tags: c, bsearch

I'm writing a vector in C.  The CVectorSearch function uses bsearch if it's sorted, and lfind if it's unsorted.  Why am I getting the warning "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" when I'm calling lfind?  It seems to work fine even when lfind is being used.

```
typedef struct
{
  void *elements;
  int logicalLength;
  int allocatedLength;
  int elementSize;
} CVector;

typedef void (*CVectorFreeElemFn)(void *elemAddr);


int CVectorSearch(const CVector *v, const void *key, 
          CVectorCmpElemFn comparefn, 
          int startIndex, bool isSorted)
{

    void * found;
    int elemSize = v->elementSize;
    int length = v->logicalLength;
    void *startAddress = (char*)v->elements + startIndex*elemSize;

    if(isSorted)
        found = bsearch(key, startAddress, length, elemSize, comparefn);
    else
        found = lfind(key, startAddress,  &length,  elemSize, comparefn);


    if(found)
        return ((char*)found - (char*)v->elements) / elemSize;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

**edit:**  Now that I've included search.h I'm getting:

```
warning: passing argument 3 of 'lfind' from incompatible pointer type
```

The program is still working correctly, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to lfind() is a pointer to `size_t` not `int` as you are passing. The `size_t` type may be of a different size than `int` on some architectures (particularly x86-64) and it is also unsigned. You have to change the type of the `length` variable.

Answer (score 4):

Have you included `<search.h>` which defines `lfind`? If a function is called without a prototype, your compiler may assume it returns `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the above questions really solve the issue as I had this problem.  The true answer I believe is the distinction between bsearch prototype and lfind prototype.  Let's takea  look

```
 void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nmemb,
              size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Versus

```
void *lfind(const void *key, const void *base, size_t *nmemb,
              size_t size, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

If you'll notice that the third parameter of the lfind function is a pointer to a size_t type not (as in the bsearch function ) a direct copied value.

Just make sure you pass in the address of the size and it'll be fine.